# Xcode - Instruments: missing symbols

Tags: swift, watchkit, xcode9, xcode-instruments

I am profiling my WatchKit extension app with time profiler but the trace is unsymbolicated:

[image]

I mean that these are all extraneous symbols for me and I can't find my methods names. If I click on any of these symbols I can see assembly code. How do I obtain the symbolicated trace?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your screenshot is showing a symbolicated trace. If the trace was not symbolicated, you would be seeing memory addresses instead of function names.

Your problem is the code from Apple's libraries is filling the detail view, making it difficult for you to find your code. Hide the code from the system libraries so you can find your code. At the bottom of the window in your screenshot there's a Call Tree button in blue. Click that button and select the Invert Call Tree and Hide System Libraries checkboxes. Selecting those checkboxes will make finding your code easier.

[image]

For anyone reading this question that has an unsymbolicated trace, the most likely problem is Instruments can't find the dSYM file that contains your debugging symbols. In Xcode 9 choose File > Symbols to locate the dSYM file, which is usually located in the same directory as the application bundle for the release version of your app.

Comment: For who is still struggling: before this, I had to tell XCode to generate the dSYM file for my project (build settings -> debug information format: "DWARF with dSYM file".

Comment: Thanks @RamyAlZuhouri, your suggestion worked for me